# how to convert 3D nii multi-class mask image file into 2D .png images

Tags: python, numpy, image-segmentation, opencv

I have a dataset containing 150 4D .nii images. only 0 and 9th-time frames have segmentation so I just selected those parts so that the new dataset contains 300 3D images which each image has 13 images in the z-axis. input_image_mask is a 3D image:

```
input_image_mask = nib.load('masks/mask0A0S9V9_sa_gt.nii' + '.gz')  
for i in range(input_mask.shape[2]):  
    input_slice_mask = np.asarray(input_mask.get_data()*255) [:,:,i].astype(np.float32)  
    if len(input_slice_mask.shape)==2:  
        input_slice_mask = np.expand_dims(input_slice_mask, axis=-1)  
        path_mask = os.path.join('Desktop/Ilkay/M/masks/2d/' + "slicem" + str(i) + ".png")  
        cv2.imwrite(path_mask, input_slice_mask)  
    else:
        # if there are multiple channel, move axis to have the channel dimension as first dimension
        input_slice_mask = np.moveaxis(input_slice_mask, 2, 0)
```

Although this code runs without a problem, the output images are black and white. while it should be a multi-class mask. I will be appreciated if anyone can help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have a data example you could upload?

Comment: @jwitos thanks for asking. how can I upload a zip file here? I couldn't upload it as an image...

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my issue and it is the solution. I hope it will help others.

```
all_img = os.listdir(path)

new_size = 256
masks = []
images = []
time = [0,9,10,11,12,23,30]
for name in all_img:
    path_ = path + name
#     print('path_number', path_)
    train_ids = next(os.walk(path_))[2]
    img_tr = nib.load(path_ + '/' + train_ids[0]).get_data()
    mask_tr = nib.load(path_ + '/' + train_ids[1]).get_data()
    img_arr = np.asarray(img_tr)
    mask_arr = np.asarray(mask_tr)
    for t in time: 
        if t in range((mask_tr.shape)[3]-1):
            
            init_mask = mask_tr[:,:,:,t].astype(np.float32)
            init_img = img_tr[:,:,:,t].astype(np.float32)

        #     print(init_mask.shape)
            for z in range((img_arr.shape)[2]):
                init2_mask = init_mask[:,:,z]
                _mask = st.resize(init2_mask, (new_size, new_size))
                masks.append(_mask)
                init2_img = init_img[:,:,z]
                _img = st.resize(init2_img, (new_size, new_size))
                images.append(_img)

masks = np.asarray(masks)
images = np.asarray(images)

np.save('mmn_masks', masks) # save the file 
np.save('mmn_images', images)
```

instead of converting to .png images, I decided to save them as NumPy array.